# How to mark which files which should be overriden during Debian package update?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg

The package manager seems to override all files during an update, regardless whether they were modified. How can I mark files which shouldn't be overriden?

Answer (score 0):

Like, config files? You put them in conffiles: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html#automatic-handling-of-configuration-files-by-dpkg